# Overloading the __ge__ and __gt__ operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-overloading

```
class Book:
    title = ''
    pages = 0

    def __init__(self, title='', pages=0):
        self.title = title
        self.pages = pages

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.pages > other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.pages >= other
```

According to this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python#comment-220271

We must explicitly say:

```
 return self.pages >= other.pages
```

For the >= or <= operators, but not for ==, !=, <, or >. 
Can someone explain why?

Comment: If you at the section titled "Comparative Literature", the code for overloading `==`, `!=`, `<`, and `>` is provided. The code explicitly uses the form you state, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Yes I'm at that section. Greater than/equal and Less than/equal require me to type "other.pages", whereas greater than and less than only require "other". I'm wondering why this is.

Comment: I tried this with a simple example. Book A with 100 pages, Book B with 200 pages. This is without explicitly comparing to "other.pages". (A>B) is False. (A>=B), (A<B), and (A<=B) are all True.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad design.  You should always write out explicitly what your comparison operators are doing.

What's actually happening is something like this:

1. You write `book_1 < book_2`.
2. Python converts this into `book_1.__lt__(book_2)`.
3. That returns `book_1.pages < book_2`.
4. Python then inverts the comparison and does `book_2.__gt__(book_1.pages)`.
5. This returns `book_2.pages > book_1.pages`, which *finally* means something.

Code is easier to understand when the reader does not have to mentally unravel something as complicated as this for a one-line comparison.  Please, never write code like that.

(It's not obvious to me why this should fail for `__le__` and `__ge__`, but it doesn't matter because you should not write code like that anyway.)

Comment: I *think* they're just wrong about `__le__` and `__ge__` behaving differently.

Comment: I tried this with a simple example. Book A with 100 pages, Book B with 200 pages. This is without explicitly comparing to "other.pages". (A>B) is False. (A>=B), (A<B), and (A<=B) are all True.